# Best way of accessing an object property that may be null?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to know if there is a simple and clean way, like a method of sorts, of accesing an object property of a certain object even touhg this property could be null, that, in consecuence, this may throw a null pointer exception, and,
if it is null, then do some other thing.

For example, I have my car object., that has two properties, Window, and Door., each one, Its an Object property.

```
Dim WCar = new Car with {.Door = new Door with {.Color = black}}

new Mgbox(WCar.Door.ToString & _
      WCar.Window.ToString) -> This may throw a null pointer exception.
```

(I do not own the class of the entity itself, and either know if this is safely coded in the constructor of the entity)

Comment: `new MsgBox(...)` what is that?  `IsNot Nothing` will tell you if something is Nothing in older versions

Comment: How would you put it?
Like this?:
If (wcar.Window isnot nothing)...

Comment: It would be faster to try it than ask on an internet web page.

Comment: I actually tried and throws an exception.

Comment: And what's the exception?  Update your post if you have new information.

Comment: Null pointer Exception.

Comment: Are you sure it's using the word "pointer"?  If the Window property is null, you would get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to read [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452)

Comment: Oh sorry, is NullReferenceException, Im basically trying to acces an object that does not exists.
Anyways, Im going with the constructor solution., thank you!

Comment: Actually, this is the real answer, It happens that Im using an older version of Visual Studio. Im clearly asking to avoid an exception, not what the exception is, in essence.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
WCar.Window?.ToString()
```

If `Window` is `Nothing` this won't throw a `NullReferenceException` anymore, but `ToString` will return `Nothing` instead. If `WCar` could also be `Nothing`:

```
WCar?.Window?.ToString()
```

Comment: Im currently working on Visual Studio 2008, It does not seem to work, it throws an error... touhg this is what I was exactly looking for. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to inherit the class and create your own setter and getter and validate if the property is null

Comment: I was Actually going to inherit the class and asign an instance of an object, in the constructor, but the question came to mind so I asked...